# How do I make pager hover on bxslider?

Tags: bxslider, jquery-hover, pager

I am using [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/) content slider. I want to get a tooltip saying the heading of the slide when I hover my mouse on pager.

here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhg31838/A5L97/3/).

So suppose if I hover on pager1, it should say slide1, when I hover on pager 4, it should say Slide4.

I tried but it broke the slider. Here is the code which I tried.

```
$('.bx-pager-link').on("mouseenter", function()({
$('.bx-pager-link').att("title = '.heading'");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a 'r' in attr and your syntax is wrong.

Try this code.

```
$('.bx-pager-link').on("mouseenter", function(){
$('.bx-pager-link').attr("title", "This is a title");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A5L97/4/)

**EDIT:** For tooltip on pager, you need to do this,

JS:

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
   pager: true,
   pagerCustom: '#bx-pager',
)};
```

HTML:

```
<div id = "bx-pager">
    <li>
        <a data-slide-index="0" title = "Tooltip text goes here" class = "slide" href="">
            Slide1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-slide-index="1" title = "Tooltip text goes here" class = "slide" href="">
            Slide2
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-slide-index="2" title = "Tooltip text goes here" class = "slide" href="">
            Slide3
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-slide-index="3" title = "Tooltip text goes here" class = "slide" href="">
            Slide4
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
```

PS: Don't forget to write "data-slide-index" in . [More](http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-1)

Comment: but it still doesn't give the div content on tooltip??